# Numpy random sampling from multiple distributions

Tags: python, numpy, random, statistics, probability

What is an efficient way to sample N numbers, where each number is a sampled by first choosing a random distribution from within a fixed predetermined list (using some specific discrete distribution), and then sampling from that chosen distribution.

So, for instance, if we want to choose 0 with probability 0.30, 1 with probability 0.30, and with probability 0.40 we want to choose any real number in `[0,1)` with uniform distribution, we can write:

```py
np.choose(
    np.random.choice(2, size=N, p=[0.6, 0.4]),
    np.vstack((
        np.random.choice(2, size=(1,N)),
        np.random.uniform(size=(1,N))
    )))
```

However this generates `N`x`D` random numbers (where `D` is the number of distributions) and uses `N`x`D` space. Is there a more efficient **vectorized** (i.e no `O(N)` python for-loops) way of achieving this?

If not in the general case, can the above specific combined distribution be somehow efficiently generated otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.unique` to determine exactly how many samples you need from each distribution. This requires a Python loop of size `O(D)`. The space complexity is `O(N)`, but the time complexity is still `O(N * D)`. You can drop it to `O(N)` by computing the sparse index for each `D`.

```
N = 10
D = 2

distributions = [
  lambda n: np.random.choice(2, size=n),
  lambda n: np.random.uniform(n),
]

ds = np.random.choice(D, p=[0.6, 0.4], size=N)
uniques, inverse, counts = np.unique(ds, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
result = np.zeros(N)
for d, c in zip(uniques, counts):
  result[inverse==d] = distributions[d](c)
```